# Why my external sdcard exists return false when sdcard insert into android device?

Tags: android, file, sd-card, android-sdcard, mount

With code like this:

```
// /mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4 is my external sdcard path
File sdcard = new File("/mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4");

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "sdcard: " + sdcard 
                + ", exists: " + sdcard.exists()            // return false
                + ", is directory: " + sdcard.isDirectory() // return false
                + ", can write: " + sdcard.canWrite());     // return false
```

Because I am working on a TV platform, so I use `Tera Term` tool to execute `ls /mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4`, I have got file list.

And also, this is my `/proc/mounts`:

```
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=111156k,nr_inodes=22811,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /mnt/media_rw tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=700,uid=1023,gid=1023 0 0
none /storage tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=751,uid=1028,gid=1028 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/secure tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=700 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=20480k,mode=771 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /system ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nomblk_io_submit,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p3 /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nomblk_io_submit,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/shell/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
/dev/block/vold/8:4 **/mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4** vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,usefree,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/udisk/sda4 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
```

---

I tried `/storage/udisk/sda4/` instead of `/mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4`, it returns `true`. Why is this?

Comment: What android version? Have you tried Context.getExternalFilesDirs?

Comment: @Henry How to confirm this? I tried `/storage/udisk/sda4/` instead of `/mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4`, it returns `true`

Comment: @MarcinJedrzejewski `minSdkVersion 16` `targetSdkVersion 21`

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions( `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml`), use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of direct path and try to execute this function:

```
private static boolean isAvilableForRead()
    {
        boolean externalStorageReadable = false;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) 
        {
            // We can read the media
            externalStorageReadable = true;
        }

        return externalStorageReadable;
    }
```

If it returns false, this is not Android SDK problem.

Comment: I tried `/storage/udisk/sda4/` instead of `/mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4`, it returns `true`. What is the problem?

Comment: use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of `/storage/udisk/sda4/` or `/mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4`! Any other devices may have its own path!

Comment: of course I will use something like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, but this is not my problem, my problem is why `/storage/udisk/sda4/` `/mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4` show difference!

Comment: First, it's not obvious from your question. Second, why do you think your application thread has an access to all the directories in file system?

Comment: and also `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` do not return external sdcard, it return the android internal sdcard, in fact I have better choice:[ExternalStorage](https://gist.github.com/paour/11403182). But for clearly, I change to hard code `/mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4` in my question.

Comment: Ok, that is my fault. At the beginning, I just want simplify the question, so I use the hard code. I am sorry to make you misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"FolderName");

// Returns true if obj is the same as this object, false otherwise.

Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Exists File :"+file.exists());

Comment: This will return the internal sdcard of android device, I use [ExternalStorage](https://gist.github.com/paour/11403182) to get my external storage, I just change to hard code `/mnt/media_rw/udisk/sda4` to simplify the question!